# Simplifying the trace of a matrix expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, linear-algebra, packages, tensors

I have a long expression involving matrices that I derived using the NCAlgebra package. Can I simplify the trace of the expression?

For example, say `b` is a scalar (commutes with all) and `x` and `y` are matrices (non-commutative). Can I simplify `Tr[b x.y.y + b y.x.y]` to `2b Tr[x.y.y]` using the properties of the trace?

---

Thanks, that is what I am going for (although I don't quite understand the code) but I only have version 8.

The expression is given below, where `e` and `r` are scalars, `q` and `v` are matrices and the double star (`**`) denotes products of non-commutative elements. I've done it by hand, but I want to be able to simplify the trace of this with *Mathematica* (and others which are much longer).

```
e^2 q ** q - e r q ** v - e r v ** q + r^2 v ** v - 
 1/12 e^3 r q ** q ** q ** v + 1/12 e^3 r q ** q ** v ** q + 
 1/24 e^2 r^2 q ** q ** v ** v + 1/12 e^3 r q ** v ** q ** q - 
 1/12 e^2 r^2 q ** v ** q ** v - 1/12 e^2 r^2 q ** v ** v ** q + 
 1/24 e r^3 q ** v ** v ** v - 1/12 e^3 r v ** q ** q ** q + 
 1/6 e^2 r^2 v ** q ** q ** v - 1/12 e^2 r^2 v ** q ** v ** q - 
 1/24 e r^3 v ** q ** v ** v + 1/24 e^2 r^2 v ** v ** q ** q - 
 1/24 e r^3 v ** v ** q ** v + 1/24 e r^3 v ** v ** v ** q
```

Comment: Can you show the "long expression"? Or at least a snippet, to get an idea of what you're looking at?

Comment: I added [tag:package], as OP has mentioned his use of NCAlgebra, and might want a solution using functions from that package.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can simplify the trace this way. First, `Tr[x.y.z]` is invariant under cyclic permutations, so `Tr[x.y.z] = Tr[y.z.x] = Tr[z.x.y]`, as described in Wikipedia's entry on [trace of a product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29). For the case of interest, this means `Tr[y.x.y]` is equal to `Tr[x.y.y]`. Hence

```
Tr[b x.y.y + b y.x.y]  = Tr[b x.y.y] + Tr[b y.x.y]
                       = b Tr[x.y.y] + b Tr[y.x.y]
                       = b Tr[x.y.y] + b Tr[x.y.y]
                       = 2b Tr[x.y.y]
```

This property (the invariance of the trace under cyclic permutations) can now be used to define a set of rules that transform the equation. Here all the `q` and `v` terms that appear with noncommutative multiplications are placed in a sort of alphabetical order (all the q's coming before the v's, respecting the cyclic permutation constraint).

```
rules = {q ** v ** v ** q -> q ** q ** v ** v, v ** q ** v ** v -> q ** v ** v ** v, 
         v ** v ** q ** q -> q ** q ** v ** v, v ** q ** q ** v -> q ** q ** v ** v, 
         v ** q ** q ** q -> q ** q ** q ** v, v ** v ** q ** v -> q ** v ** v ** v, 
         v ** v ** v ** q -> q ** v ** v ** v, q ** q ** v ** q -> q ** q ** q ** v, 
         q ** v ** q ** q -> q ** q ** q ** v, v ** q ** v ** q -> q ** v ** q ** v};
```

Now, with your equation above defined as `eqn`, the rules can be applied:

```
eqn //. rules
```

and the result is quite satisfyingly short

```
e^2 q ** q - e r q ** v - e r v ** q + r^2 v ** v + 
    1/6 e^2 r^2 q ** q ** v ** v - 1/6 e^2 r^2 q ** v ** q ** v
```

I may not have all the possible rules and remember that this is only true when you are taking the Trace! I don't have version 8 to check, but this doesn't use any advanced functionality, so it ought to work fine.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you certainly can if you have version 9 and don't mind using the (quite verbose) tensor notation:

```
Assuming[
 {b ∈ Complexes, (x | y) ∈ Matrices[{n, n}]},
 TensorReduce@
  TensorContract[
   b TensorContract[TensorProduct[x, y, y], {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}] + 
   b TensorContract[TensorProduct[y, x, y], {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}],
   {{1, 2}}
  ]
 ]
(* -> 2 b TensorContract[TensorProduct[x, y, y], {{1, 6}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}] *)
```

While *Mathematica* certainly knows the relevant identities, it apparently doesn't know how `Dot` and `Tr` are represented as contractions of tensor products, so you have to write it all out explicitly. I'll leave it to you to decide whether this was worth the trouble or not.

Answer (score 4):

You could use my `TensorSimplify` package to do this. Install the paclet with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

Once installed, you can load the package with:

```
<<TensorSimplify`
```

**Simple example**

Here is `TensorSimplify` applied to your simple example:

```
$Assumptions = b ∈ Complexes && (x|y) ∈ Matrices[{n, n}];
TensorSimplify[
    Tr[b x.y.y + b y.x.y]
]
```

> 2 b Tr[y.x.y]

**More complicated example**

For your more complicated example:

```
expr = e^2 q ** q - e r q ** v - e r v ** q + r^2 v ** v - 
1/12 e^3 r q ** q ** q ** v + 1/12 e^3 r q ** q ** v ** q + 
1/24 e^2 r^2 q ** q ** v ** v + 1/12 e^3 r q ** v ** q ** q - 
1/12 e^2 r^2 q ** v ** q ** v - 1/12 e^2 r^2 q ** v ** v ** q + 
1/24 e r^3 q ** v ** v ** v - 1/12 e^3 r v ** q ** q ** q + 
1/6 e^2 r^2 v ** q ** q ** v - 1/12 e^2 r^2 v ** q ** v ** q - 
1/24 e r^3 v ** q ** v ** v + 1/24 e^2 r^2 v ** v ** q ** q - 
1/24 e r^3 v ** v ** q ** v + 1/24 e r^3 v ** v ** v ** q;
```

To use `TensorSimplify` we need to change [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply) to [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot):

```
$Assumptions = (e|r) ∈ Complexes && (v|q) ∈ Matrices[{n, n}];

TensorSimplify[
    Tr[expr] /. NonCommutativeMultiply -> Dot
]
```

> e^2 Tr[q.q] - 2 e r Tr[v.q] + r^2 Tr[v.v] + 1/6 e^2 r^2 Tr[v.q.q.v] - 
>    1/6 e^2 r^2 Tr[v.q.v.q]

Answer (score 0):

[NCAlgebra](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC) supports a trace type operator so that

```
SetCommutative[b]
tr[b x ** y ** y + b y ** x ** y]
```

will result in

> 2 b tr[x**y^2]

out of the box.

P.S.: We are in the process of updating NCAlgebra so you might want to try our latest beta version from [here](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/tree/v6.0.0), which you can install as a paclet.