# How to represent $2n \times 2n$ Dirac matrices in terms of Pauli matrices in block matrix format?

Tags: matrix, physics

I am interested in building matrices out of smaller matrices, do calculations, and express the results in a block matrix form, in terms of the smaller matrices.

For example, say I define the following $2\times 2$ **Pauli matrices**

```
σ0 = PauliMatrix[0]; (*{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}*)
σ1 = PauliMatrix[1]; (*{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}*)
σ2 = PauliMatrix[2]; (*{{0, -I}, {I, 0}}*)
σ3 = PauliMatrix[3]; (*{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}*)
```

In matrix format they look like
$$\sigma0=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
 \end{array}\right),
\sigma1=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
  0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right),
\sigma2=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
  0 & -i \\
  i & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right),
\sigma3=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 \\
 \end{array}\right).
$$

Then, I define

```
O2 = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}};
```

and the following $4\times 4$ **Dirac matrices**

```
γ0 = ArrayFlatten[{{σ0, O2}, {O2, σ0}}];
γ1 = ArrayFlatten[{{O2, σ1}, {-σ1, O2}}];
γ2 = ArrayFlatten[{{O2, σ2}, {-σ2, O2}}];
γ3 = ArrayFlatten[{{O2, σ3}, {-σ3, O2}}];
```

For example, $\gamma2$ has the following matrix form
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
  0 & 0 & 0 & -i \\
  0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
  0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
  -i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right),$$
and
$\gamma1.\gamma2$ has the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
  -i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & i & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
 \end{array}\right).$$

> What can I do to display $\gamma2$ in the form

$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
  0 & \sigma2 \\
  -\sigma2 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right)$$

> and $\gamma1.\gamma2$ in the form

$$\left(\begin{array}{rr}
  -i \sigma3 & 0 \\
  0 & -i \sigma3 \\
 \end{array}\right)?$$

Note that

```
MatrixForm[{{O2, σ1}, {-σ1, O2}}]
```

works to display them as I need only as long as I don't define the symbols $O2$ and $\sigma2$, otherwise the result is in the usual matrix form.

Comment: Please, do not post images of your code. Include it. Go over the help, to how to do it.

Comment: You can display the matrices as `MatrixForm[{{O2, \[Sigma]1}, {-\[Sigma]1, O2}}]`. Regarding the multiplication of matrices consisting in blocks I suggest you read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33530/keep-order-of-mulciplication-in-matrix-production?rq=1)

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas: I replaced the pictures with with code. As for MatrixForm[{{O2, \[Sigma]1}, {-\[Sigma]1, O2}}], it works to display them as I need only as long as I don't define the symbols O2 and σ2, otherwise the result is in the usual matrix form. And I need to have the sigmas and gammas  defined, but the result simplified into a block matrix format, not just to write them in the final form after I do the calculation myself, but to use Mathematica to find the final form automatically.

Comment: Have you looked at [FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io/) ? I think it has some cool functionality for Dirac algebra.

Comment: @Sumit: this FeynCalc looks great, I will look at it closer, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.

1. Break your matrix into $2 \times2$ blocks.
2. Express the block in terms of Pauli matrices.

For step 2, I am using the method of @ybeltukov defined in [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61274/8070) of [Expressing a matrix in terms of four basis matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61245/expressing-a-matrix-in-terms-of-four-basis-matrices).

```
sigma[M__] := Module[{submat, basis, fb, nrm, cf},
               submat = Partition[M, {2, 2}, 2]; (*2x2 submatrices*)
               basis = PauliMatrix[#] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3};(*Pauli Matrices*)
               fb = Flatten[basis, {{1}, {2, 3}}];
               nrm = Diagonal[fb.ConjugateTranspose[fb]]; (*norm of basis*)
               cf[m_] := Flatten[m].ConjugateTranspose[fb]/nrm; (*coeff for σ*)
               Map[{"I", "σ1", "σ2", "σ3"}.cf[#] &, submat, {2}]]
```

The last line is for output text.

**Example 1**

```
sigma[γ2] // MatrixForm
```

> $
> \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & \text{$\sigma $2} \\
>  -\text{$\sigma $2} & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
sigma[γ1.γ2] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  -i \text{$\sigma $3} & 0 \\
>  0 & -i \text{$\sigma $3} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Example 2: Visualising `Outer` product**

```
M = ArrayFlatten@Outer[Times, σ2, σ3];
MatrixForm[M]
sigma[M] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  0 & 0 & -i & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & i \\
>  i & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$
>   $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  0 & -i \text{$\sigma $3} \\
>  i \text{$\sigma $3} & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: This works like charm even for larger matrices containing Pauli matrices!

Comment: @CristiStoica, this method should work with any orthogonal basis set. It is easier to construct higher order Dirac matrices with `Outer` if you don't want to write them explicitly. I give an example (Example 2) for that.