# Calculate Dot product of a TensorProduct

Tags: symbolic, tensors

Using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/74039/31209)

```
Clear[x, y];
$Assumptions = (x | y) \[Element] Vectors[2];

tensorExpand[expr_] := 
 Simplify[TensorExpand[expr] /. 
     Thread[{x, y} -> IdentityMatrix[2]]] /. 
   l_List :> SparseArray[l] /. s_SparseArray :> toSymbols[ArrayRules@s]

toSymbols[ruleList_] := 
 Total[ruleList /. 
   HoldPattern[Rule[a_, b_]] :> 
    Times[Apply[TensorProduct, a /. Thread[{1, 2} -> {x, y}]], b]]
```

I want to do something like (it don't even run):

```
Inner[Dot, a TensorProduct[x, x] + c TensorProduct[y, x], 
b TensorProduct[x, y], Plus]
```

to get zero as result and

```
Inner[Dot, a TensorProduct[x, x] + c TensorProduct[y, x], 
b TensorProduct[x, x], Plus]
```

`a b` for this case, just like if I was working with Dirac's notation:
$$
(a\vert + + \rangle + c \vert -+\rangle,b\vert + +\rangle) = ab
$$
where $(\,,\,)$ is the dot product.

I think that `Inner` is inadequate for this task, but is the only approach that I have.

**Edit**: I'm trying this because I'm using 20 qubits and using something like `KroneckerProduct` isn't suitable for my case.

Comment: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7622/

Comment: Do you need the tensor properties, or do you just want to manipulate expressions containing the kets, and perform inner products?

Comment: I am assuming you want to manipulate these expressions symbolically. Unfortunately, symbolic tensors aren't well integrated with the rest of *Mathematica* (so far, anyway). In particular, functions like `Simplify`, `Dot`, or `Inner` don't really do anything too useful with them. You would have to use `TensorContract` in place of `Dot` or `Inner`, and `TensorReduce` in place of `Simplify`, which [can be awkward](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26688/26700#26700).

Comment: Well, 20 qubits is really "nothing". You just need to represent your basis states as sparse vectors. Then you can do even much more. Kronecker product works well will sparse tensors (see the documentation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested already in the comments it is easier to work in a concrete basis
e.g. as follows:

```
x = {1, 0} ; y = {0, 1}; bv[a_, b_] := Flatten[KroneckerProduct[a, b]];
```

Then you can calculate your particular examples easily:

```
(a*bv[x, x] + c bv[y, x]).(b bv[x, y])
(* 0 *)
(a*bv[x, x] + c bv[x, y]).(b bv[x, x])
(* a*b *)
```

Using the symbolic tensors in Mathematica is somewhat awkward to my opinion.